# Making separate columns for my data in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is the format of the text file I'm working with:
[image]

Currently I'm trying to send data from a text file to a csv file. I'm using Pandas to read the text file and convert it to a csv. The following is my current product:
[image]

As you can see, column A has my index, but column B contains the rest of the row. What I would like is for each  piece of data to have its own column.

Currently this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
Pandora_File = 'file'
out_file = 'file'

data = pd.read_csv(Pandora_File,header = None)

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df.to_csv(out_file,sep=",")
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the purpose to read csv file (you use `read_csv` function while reading txt file), and then to save it again as csv file, please? Do you try to change separator?

Comment: @kosist I'm looking to be able to grab a lot of similar txt files, reformat them to csv files, and then analyze the data within them quickly. As they are within the txt files they aren't very manageable. I can add an edit with a picture of the txt file I'm using.

Comment: please, add it - it could help. Because now it seems, that your txt file is already csv file, but maybe just with another delimiter (csv files, at the end, could have not just comma as delimiters...).

Comment: @Kosist Thanks so much! you solved my issue! Of course, I now have more in my way but thanks for helping me over the hurdle!

Comment: honestly, I still don't know how to parse that file - b/c I expected to see there some obvious separator, but seems, that it is not there... What solution did you find, please?